# How to properly pass a string through multiple child constructors to parent. C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I'm a college student in my first C++ class. I'm in need of some help for the current homework.

The goal I'm trying to accomplish is to create a new object (`Rabbit`) and pass the name `pete` from Rabbit > Mammal > Animal, to be set there privately and referenced later (The pointer is referenced later to print out the name).

```
string pete;
Rabbit* RabbitP = new Rabbit(pete);
```

I have the header file for `Rabbit` as so:

```
#include <string>

class Rabbit :
    public Mammal
{
public:
    Rabbit(std::string tempname) : Mammal(tempname){ }
    Rabbit();
    ~Rabbit();
```

I'm attempting to use the initialization list to pass the name of the `Rabbit` to `Mammal`, then to `Animal` from there. In the `Mammal` and `Animal` headers I have this:

```
#include <string>

class Mammal :
    public Animal
{
public:
    Mammal(std::string tempname) : Animal(tempname) {}
    Mammal();
    ~Mammal();
};
```

```
#include <string>

class Animal // BASE
{
private:
    std::string aName;
public:
    Animal(std::string tempname);
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
```

The `Animal.cpp` containing the function is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Animal::Animal()
{
}

Animal::~Animal()
{
}

Animal::Animal(string tempname)
{
    aName = tempname;
}

void Animal::Breathe()
{
    std::cout << "Takes a deep breath." << std::endl;
}

void Animal::Move()
{
    std::cout << "Jiggle your limbs around" << std::endl;
}

string Animal::GetName(Animal*)
{
    return aName;
}
```

Using the debugger in Visual Studio, I can see that it is moving up the constructors properly, but it is not passing anything. It feels like I'm somewhat on the right track, but what am I missing?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean in your last statement _"not passing anything"_.  Your classes look fine, and the string should be propagated up.  It would be more correct for it to be `const std::string&` but that won't make a large difference.  In your top example, you define an empty string and then use that to initialize a `Rabbit` instance.  Did you expect the string to contain the text "pete" by any chance?

Comment: Yes I was thinking it would contain 'pete' I tried the answer response's suggestion of using Rabbit RabbitP("pete"); to pass it. Am I still using string pete; or doing something like string pete = "pete";?

Comment: Yeah, defining a variable named `pete` does not give it magical powers such as initializing it with a string value the same as its identifier.  Use `string pete = "pete"` or `string pete = "anything you like"`.  Or, like the person who answered this question suggests, you can just pass it into the constructor as a literal: `new Rabbit("pete")`.  I'm voting to close this question, as it's unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Note there is very rarely a good reason to use the `new` or `delete` keyword in modern C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string pete;
```

This calls the `string` default constructor and creates an empty string. You now have an empty string in the variable `pete`.

```
Rabbit* RabbitP = new Rabbit(pete);
```

This creates a new Rabbit, calling the constructor and passing an empty string. You should expect the name in `Animal` to be set to `""`.

If you want the name to be "Pete," call it and pass the string "Pete." If you don't use pointers (which here it looks like you don't need to) that'd look like:

```
Rabbit RabbitP("Pete");
```

Comment: Yes, you're right it was returning "". I used your suggestion and got the error 'Animal':base class undefined. I didn't change anything else other than the lines you quoted.

Comment: @rbrducky can you show a pastebin or something of the updated code? Note that I also changed the **type** of `RabbitP` from a pointer to a regular old `Rabbit`, so that may have changed things.

Comment: I changed any pointer arguments to just Animal arguments. The only code I'm looking at right now is the string pete, the line you suggested and a cout to test.

Comment: @rbrducky there's definitely something else that changed though. The only way I can help is if you show all the code, otherwise we'd just be going back and forth guessing.

Comment: Yes sorry it was fault on my end. It's working now without problems, thank you very much for helping!

Comment: @rbrducky Happy to help, I'm glad things are working!